# Insert data into mysql using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I'm trying to insert data to mysql, tried everything but nothing worked

here is my code :

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rating-btn").click( function(){
      var teaching=$("#teaching").val;
      var marking=$("#marks").val;
      var helpfulness=$("#helpfulness").val;
      var difficulty=$("#difficulty").val;
      var grade=$("#grade").val;
      var com=$("#com").val;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"db/ajax.php",
    data:"teaching=" + teaching +"&marking="+ marking +"&helpfulness="+ helpfulness
    +"&difficulty="+difficulty+"&grade="+grade+"&com="+com,
    dataType: "dataString",
    cache: "true",
    success: function(msg,string,jqXHR){
      $("#results").html(msg+string+jqXHR);
    }
    });

  });

});
```

ajax.php

```
<?php 

 error_reporting(0);
 require 'db/connect.php';

    $teaching = $_POST['teaching'];
    $teaching = mysql_real_escape_string($teaching);

    $marking = $_POST['marking'];
    $marking  = mysql_real_escape_string($marking);

    $helpfulness = $_POST['helpfulness'];
    $helpfulness  = mysql_real_escape_string($helpfulness);

    $difficulty = $_POST['difficulty'];
    $difficulty = mysql_real_escape_string($difficulty);

    $grade = $_POST['grade'];
    $grade = mysql_real_escape_string($grade);

    $com= $_POST['com'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ratings VALUES ( '', '{$teaching}', '{$marking}' ,'{$helpfulness}', '{$difficulty}' ,'{$grade}' , '2' , '{$com}')";

   mysqli_query($sql);

?>
```

connect.php

```
<?php
$db= new mysqli('localhost','root','','instructors');

if($db->connect_errno){
    die("we are having some problems");
}

?>
```

I tried to the sql code and it worked in the *phpmyadmin* page.

So what is missing that is preventing the data from going into the database?

UPDATE:
when i try to echo all the variables and thier values apears normally
i also tried to do this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `ratings` VALUES ( '', '3.5', '2.5' ,'4.5', '2.5' ,'1' , '2' , 'hello how are you')";
```

it does not insert this values to the database

but when i  put the same sql code in the phpmyadmin its adds a row perfectly

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, why not use [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) (`$comment` has NOT been escaped), and you're simply assuming DB operations can never fail. Bad assumption. Try `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())` and enjoy the error messages.

Comment: You need to do basic debugging before you come to us. Not to mention you gave us no issue to go off of. "Not working" isn't descriptive in the slightest.

Comment: OH, and your `data` in JS is totally wrong. You're building `a=bc=de=f`. it should be `a=b&c=d&e=f`

Comment: i added "or die" method and no error found

Comment: common guys im newbie

Comment: It doesn't work because your **main** problem is that you're connecting with `mysqli_` then querying with `mysql_` - Those two MySQL APIs do **not** mix.

Comment: @MarcB *"Try `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())` and enjoy the error messages."* ^^^ Look again.

Comment: i tried mysqli, making them a=b&c=d
and then i added or die and i did not find any error on the log cause i already debugged everthing and still no result in the database

Comment: how to check the variables values cause when i try to echo them nothing apears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, your Js-code has some missing paranthesis. >ou should replace "val" with the function call "val()"

```
  var teaching=$("#teaching").val();
  var marking=$("#marks").val();
  var helpfulness=$("#helpfulness").val();
  var difficulty=$("#difficulty").val();
  var grade=$("#grade").val();
  var com=$("#com").val();
```

Afterwards, you should get some values in PHP-land, which can be inserted.

Additionally, you are mixing procedural and OOP-code.

```
 mysqli_query($sql);
```

... is at least missing the connection as first parameter. But since you saved an instance of mysqli_connection already in $db try replacing it with:

```
$db->query($sql);
```

Comment: i noticed that and corrected it but still does not insert to the database

Answer (score 0):

What everyone said about mysql and mysqli. Plus you have to add the & between the vars.

```
data:"teaching=" + teaching +"&marking="+ marking +"&helpfulness="+ helpfulness
    +"&difficulty="+difficulty+"&grade="+grade+"&comment="+comment,
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed my problem by just using the object $db that i already created in connect.php in the ajax.php

instead of writing

```
 query(&sql)
```

the solution is :

```
$db->query($sql);
```

thanks for everyone for the help.